# Where to ask for advice on senior project

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to ask the following question. Which Stack Exchange site would be the most appropriate?

> I need some guidance for my senior project. I would like to have your opinion regarding its feasibility (I have about 2 months and I'm willing to learn on the go)
>
> The main idea behind my project is that you can post a URL that can be a video (YouTube, daily motion...) or an audio file and the App will be able to play the audio in background. Several links can be added to create a Playlist and it will be available for a period of time. The Playlist can be shared on the main feed (if you're a logged in user) or privately via a link.
>
> I would really appreciate your feedback and support, noting that it's a senior project and it is not my intention to breach any copyrights.

Comment: *[Culminating project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culminating_project)* - *"A culminating project (also known as a* ***senior project***, *grad project or exit project), is a project that challenges high school seniors to demonstrate their academic knowledge in an experiential way (in most cases)."*

Comment: Related: *[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)*

Answer (score 5):

IMHO the question that you want to ask doesn't look to be good fit for Stack Exchange as it looks to "require more focus" and be "primarily opinion-based".

Here are some post that might guide you to find related sites

- [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/289691)
- [Where can I ask a question about developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685/88163)

Once you find one site that you find interesting, take a look to their "tour" and the "How to ask" help articles.

Also you may ask about the academic related stuff for senior projects in https://academia.stackexchange.com/, i.e. questions tagged with [project-design](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-design) could guide you about how to ask for advice about an academic project.

Comment: I don't believe this would be on topic for Academia as it's specific to a particular field, plus it's about high school (neither of which is on topic for that site).